# Как рекурсивно перебрать элементы таблицы и из их значения сформировать новую таблицу?

Tags: sql, postgresql, for

Есть таблица:

```
 ________________________
|id |value|timestamp     |
 ________________________
| 0 |  3  |time and date |
 ________________________
| 1 | 40  |time and date |
```

Необходимо сформировать из нее новую, беря каждый `id` и выводя 1 и время +1сек `value` раз.

То есть, если значение value =3, тогда в выводимую таблицы добавить

```
_____________________
|1 |time and date+1 |
_____________________
|1 |time and date+2 |
_____________________
|1 |time and date+3 |
```

Так поступить со всеми элементами `id` и в результате сформировать одну таблицу.

Кодом это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
for($i=0;$i<max(id);$i++){
    for ($y=0;$y<value[id];$y){
       echo 1,"time and date"+$y
   }
}
```

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, timestamp + (generate_series || 's')::interval
  from tablename cross join generate_series(1, ?)
    where id = ?;
```

---

```
with s as(
  select generate_series(1, ?) as s
)
select t.id, t.timestamp + (s.s || 's')::interval
  from tablename t, s
    where t.id = ?;
```

---

```
 ?column? |      ?column?       
----------+---------------------
        1 | 2019-05-28 12:45:01
        1 | 2019-05-28 12:45:02
        1 | 2019-05-28 12:45:03
        1 | 2019-05-28 12:45:04
        1 | 2019-05-28 12:45:05
(5 rows)
```

Comment: @user3660833, вам помог ответ?

Comment: Спасибо , то что доктор прописал   :)

Comment: тогда пометьте его "принятым"

Comment: @user3660833 Теперь у вас достаточно репутации, чтобы нажать стрелечку вверх слева от ответа, так доктора советуют.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь в решении и ликбез по использованию ресурса :)